# Json to ListView - Can't convert type to IEnumerable- Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to bind my json data to a list view. I have an error at topList.ItemsSource = recipes; which is "cannot implicitly convert type Recipes to IEnumerable. Are you missing a cast?"

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="topList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#

```
        Recipes recipes;
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadJson();

        }

        void ReadJson()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Recipes.json");

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                recipes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recipes>(json);

                topList.ItemsSource = recipes;

            }
        }
```

Class

```
public class Recipes
    {
        public List<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
    }

    public class Recipe
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Img { get; set; }
    }
```

Json File

```
{
  "Recipe": [
    {
      "title": "Satay Chicken Skewers",
      "img": "satayChicken.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sweet Potato Spinach Feta Pie",
      "img": "SweetPotatoSpinachFetaPie.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recipes` is a single object.  `recipes.Recipe` is a **list** (or `IEnumerable`)

```
topList.ItemsSource = recipes.Recipe;
```

Comment: When I try this, my program enters break mode - System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: according to the code you posted it should be.  What type does it think that `recipes.Recipe` is?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List[Recipe]

Comment: that's correct.  There must be another line causing the exception.  Check the stack trace

Comment: When I remove that line, the program starts at least, so I don't see how it could be another line. I've also tried to wrap it around a try and catch but it goes straight to that break mode and only gives me that error that I mentioned in my first comment and it doesn't get the chance to run the catch statement. I have no idea what is causing the error...

Comment: please look at the stack trace for the root cause of the error.  Also, note that the the casing of the properties in your C# does not match your JSON.

Comment: Okay so I just closed my program and opened it again and it doesn't throw that error anymore... but It's not showing the listview at all. Am I doing something wrong when binding the title?

Comment: did you fix the json casing problem I just mentioned?  Have you verified that your json data is getting correctly deserialized into `recipes`?

Comment: yes, the json data is deserialized correctly. Sorry but I have that break mode again. I'm still learning so I'm not 100% sure of what you mean by trace stack.. If you mean the Output --  then that's the only error... **System.InvalidCastException:** 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: you still have not answered my question about fixing the casing.  Google "visual studio stack trace" to learn how to use that.  You are *also* missing a `ViewCell` within your `DataTemplate`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

Comment: Sorry yes, I fixed the casting. It seems like that missing ViewCell was the cause of the problem. So sorry for all this effort for such a silly mistake. I appreciate your help a lot, Jason.